# Entity generator

Tags: java, code-generation

Does anybody know if there is any program able to create annotation based entity beans classes from a SQL table? I need to create Entity generator tool, can any one suggest me some jar files for generate entity from database table grammatically  ? I need to generate when I click generate button.  thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know what you're looking for reverse engineer your database i.e. creating entity from database ...answer is `Dal4j` refer [http://sourceforge.net/p/dal4j/wiki/Home/] and use

> dal4j-0.3.2-binary-[1](http://sourceforge.net/p/dal4j/wiki/Home/)release.jar**

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be of help to you - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E27086_01/help/oracle.eclipse.tools.orm.doc/html/files/genJPAEntities.html

Answer (score 1):

if you are using eclipse this may be of help http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/.

It does what you ask for.

Comment: Chimpsky: Friend I need to generate entity dynamically through the spring side program. When I click generate button in my application it should generate entity from database. can you suggest me any tool for that please..